# withCredentials property is not supported in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, jquery

I am using HTML5, jQuery 1.6.1, jQuery Mobile 1.0.1.

I am using below code to make an Ajax request. It's working fine in Chrome but I got the below error while testing in Firefox 14.0.1.

> Use of XMLHttpRequest's withCredentials attribute is no longer supported in the synchronous mode in window context.

Code:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   dataType: "json",        
   async: false,
   beforeSend: function (xhr){          
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', make_base_auth(UserId, Password)); 
  },
  xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: true
  },
   success:function(data){                  
   console.log("Success");          
 },
 error:function(xhr,err){
    console.log("Failed" );
 }          
});
```

Please help me out on this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The solution is simple : don't use `async: false` in `$.ajax`.

It's deprecated in newer version and you don't need it. It was always a bad idea to use it. Execute what you need to do with result from the success callback (just like your `console.log`).

From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (1.8) :

> Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser,
>   disabling any actions while the request is active. As of jQuery 1.8,
>   the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you
>   must use the complete/success/error callbacks.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this answer an extra 50 times.  Thank you so much - you just ended a two hour bug fix session.

Comment: I disagree that you should never use synch mode. We have an enterprise site that has to do some server side processing when the the user closes the page. The only way to reliably do this is to use the unload function and make a synchronized ajax request. These seem to fail if the browser closes too quickly but only in certain browsers. Also the callback functions will never get executed unless you use synch since the browser is gone before the ajax call finishes. Of course any synch calls need to be designed to be fast or it will be annoying to the user.

Comment: @George Doing some server side processing when the user closes the page is a terrible practice. Don't do that, it can't be reliable due to the nature of HTTP. Designing an application for the web starts with avoiding this kind of antipatterns.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this thread ina couple places so will update an answer to this one:
I tried adjusting the async to true, using MANY different posts and other properties, but it was the default action of the form submit that was causing the page to refresh:

```
                    submitSuggestion: function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        submitComment(viewModel);
                    },
                });
```

the e.preventDefault() prevented the normal submit behavior, which is the reload page.  That behavior generates the xml redirection errors since  the default form submittal USES that functions.

Try adding preventDefault if you're getting a refresh you didn't call for!